# How to configure "Commit text links" feature in SourceTree for windows across many repositories

Tags: configuration, atlassian-sourcetree

**TL;DR**: SourceTree for Windows recently added the "commit text links" feature, but it appears that the replacements must be set up per-repository. Is there a way to apply them globally or a config file that could be modified programmatically to set them?

**Long version**: The "commit text links" feature looks incredibly useful but I have a bit of a problem: We have about a dozen JIRA projects and over 25 repositories that each of them could be related to (none of them are 1-to-1 mappings). While I could set up a single regular expression to match each of the JIRA projects, it's a bit much to ask all of my developers to set it up through the UI for each and every repository. To really take advantage of this I ideally need to be able to give them instructions on a single file to modify or I need to generate a setup script that I can distribute to our developers.

Is there a config file that this setting is saved in? I was expecting to see it in something like .hg/hgrc but I couldn't find anything. I also couldn't find any relevant settings in the SourceTree Program Files folder.

Alternatively, is there a global or default setting that can be applied across all repositories? That plus the regex version could make setup significantly less painful if still manual.

Thanks!

(Note: I'm in version 1.3.3.0 of SourceTree for Windows, which I believe is the most recent stable version)

Comment: I too am having this issue, I'm trying to work out the best approach; rather than copy+pasting it multiple times, then trying to commit the sourcetree config it into git.

Comment: I also asked this on the "Atlassian Answers" site https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/246903/link-to-jira-issue-in-commit-message-set-repository-settings-via-config-file but got no reply there, either. I ultimately set up my personal most-used repositories manually, and left it at that.

Comment: The approach I took was using a big regex. It ended up being something like ((a|b|c|d)-\d+)   and just pasted into the different repositories as a manual replace link. Hacky but easier than adding 5 projects on each repo

Comment: Improved regex, was just: ([a-zA-Z]*-\d+). But this obviously will do it for anything matching the form AAAA-####

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be a bit late, but I've found a relatively easy way to do this.

Underneath your .hg/.git folder within your repository should exist a file called 'sourcetreeconfig.' This is where the links live and can be manually edited.

First make sure that you have closed all of the existing repository tabs within sourcetree, and additionally close sourcetree afterwards. Then, (assuming you have already configured a repository) copy the  block from the respective repository's sourcetreeconfig and do a replace across all of your sourcetreeconfig files. This would be if you have multiple tied to the same project. It should be relatively easy to throw something together that can configure for different projects, just replace the url/project within the config.

Upon reopening sourcetree, each of your repositories should reflect this change.

This was performed using version 1.6.5.0 of sourcetree.

Answer (score 2):

## Programmatic Solution

Here in late 2019, the ability to globally configure commit text links in Sourcetree 3.2.6 for Windows still does not exist. Since this question was one of the few hits with a decent answer, I figured I would add an automated solution to the answers. I'm not a programmer, and I know the RegEx isn't the best, but this simple PowerShell script I cobbled together gets the job done. Make sure Sourcetree is closed before you run the script.

1. Copy the `sourcelinker` script into a **Notepad++** or similar text editor application.
2. In order get the specific string for your setup, configure one of your Git repos with one or more commit text links specific to your organization.
   A. Launch **Sourcetree**, select a **Git** repo, and click **Settings**.
   B. In the **Repository Settings** window, click the **Advanced** tab.
   C. In the **Commit text links** area, click **Add**.
   D. From the **Replacement type** drop-down list, select **Other**.
   E. Enter the **Regex pattern** and **Link to URL** for your specific setup, and click **OK**.
   F. In the **Repository Settings** window, click **OK**.
   G. Close **Sourcetree**.

   3. Navigate to the **.git** sub-directory of the repo you configured, and open **sourcetreesonfig.json**.
   4. Copy everything starting with `"CommitTextLinks": [` through the closing bracket and comma `],`. For example:

```
"CommitTextLinks": [
    {
      "$id": "11",
      "LinkType": 99,
      "Regex": "[fF][bB][#\\s]*(\\d+)",
      "LinkToUrl": "https://companyname.fogbugz.com/f/cases/$1",
      "Project": null,
      "RootUrl": null,
      "Description": "[fF][bB][#\\s]*(\\d+) => https://companyname.fogbugz.com/f/cases/$1"
    }
  ],
```

6. Paste the copied content into your `sourcelinker` script *between the single quotes that follow* `$New1 =`.
7. Save the script as `sourcelinker.ps1`.
8. Copy `sourcelinker.ps1` to the root folder where your Git repos reside.
9. Right-click the script, and select **Run with PowerShell**.
10. Launch **Sourcetree**, and check the **Commit text links** for your other Git repos.

### Sourcelinker script

This script example contains Regex examples that link to Fogbugz and handles variations such as:

- case12345
- fb12345
- bugzid12

#### Script

```
# Sourcelinker script
$InputFiles = Get-Item ".\*\.git\sourcetreeconfig.json"
$Old1 = '"CommitTextLinks": null,'
$New1 = '"CommitTextLinks": [
    {
      "$id": "9",
      "LinkType": 99,
      "Regex": "[bB][Uu][gG][sSzZ]\\s*[Ii][Dd]s?\\s*[#:; ]+(\\d+)",
      "LinkToUrl": "https://companyname.fogbugz.com/f/cases/$1",
      "Project": null,
      "RootUrl": null,
      "Description": "[bB][Uu][gG][sSzZ]\\s*[Ii][Dd]s?\\s*[#:; ]+(\\d+) => https://companyname.fogbugz.com/f/cases/$1"
    },
    {
      "$id": "10",
      "LinkType": 99,
      "Regex": "[cC][aA][Ss][Ee]+\\s*(\\d+)",
      "LinkToUrl": "https://companyname.fogbugz.com/f/cases/$1",
      "Project": null,
      "RootUrl": null,
      "Description": "[cC][aA][Ss][Ee]+\\s*(\\d+) => https://companyname.fogbugz.com/f/cases/$1"
    },
    {
      "$id": "11",
      "LinkType": 99,
      "Regex": "[fF][bB][#\\s]*(\\d+)",
      "LinkToUrl": "https://companyname.fogbugz.com/f/cases/$1",
      "Project": null,
      "RootUrl": null,
      "Description": "[fF][bB][#\\s]*(\\d+) => https://companyname.fogbugz.com/f/cases/$1"
    }
  ],'
$InputFiles | ForEach {
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($Old1,$New1) | Set-Content -Path $_.Fullname
}
```

Solution inspired thanks to suggestion by [Andrew Pearce from this thread](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/find-and-replace-strings-in-multiple-files/).